# Parallelize already linear-time algorithm

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

In practice, is there any case that an already linear-time algorithm need to be parallelized? My teacher argues that it is not worth it but I don't believe so.

Comment: that would depend on the number of elements to be usually processed by that algorithm, and the dependency these elements have between each other, and of course also on whether there's even a parallel processor available to get some speedup

Comment: I would say it's entirely the wrong level of thinking. If it's too slow (however fast that may be), and it can be parallelized, then it's worth it. Regardless of any time complexities and whatnot. In the real world, the real time matters. And if it's not too slow, then it doesn't matter. Not even if it's actually an exponential-time algorithm.

Answer (score 13):

Your teacher is mistaken.  The run-time complexity (O(n), O(log n), etc.) of the single-CPU algorithm has no bearing on whether or not it will benefit from parallelization.

Changing your code from using 1 CPU to using K CPUs will at best divide the run time by a factor of K.  Since you can't arbitrarily create CPUs out of thin air, K is effectively a constant.  So, the run-time complexity is not affected by parallelization.  All you can hope to do is get a constant factor improvement.

Which isn't to say that it's not worth doing - in some cases, a two-fold improvement is hugely beneficial.  Plus, in a massively parallel system of thousands of CPUs, that constant gets pretty big.

Comment: +1, but K is only a constant if your referring to a single system.  If your talking about the performance of an algorithm over a range of differing systems, K becomes a variable.

Comment: @Shane MacLaughlin - K is still a constant as far as run-time complexity is concerned, because it is not a function of n (the length of the input).

Comment: +1 for "Since you can't arbitrarily create CPUs out of thin air" :P

Comment: "Changing your code from using 1 CPU to using K CPUs will at best divide the run time by a factor of K." - not necessarily true. While it doesn't often occur in real-life problems, there is the possibility of super-linear speedup (see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup)

Comment: @nyarlathotep - Interesting, but I wish they provided references in that section.  Most of their arguments (cache, etc.) seem to result in a larger constant factor increase, not a change from O(n) to O(log n).  See Amdahl's Law - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law.

Comment: Ahh, when Amdahl's Law turns up, I have to throw in Gustafson's (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustafson%27s_law) ;). But more to the previous point: Yes, cache/memory can be a reason for superlinear speedup - simply breaking down the problem into so small parts that they fit into one CPU's memory more easily - but how is that increasing the constant factor? If you consider e.g. a search algorithm where you have the data spread over multiple machines, you will definitely see superlinear speedup to one machine accessing all the search data from a huge storage device...

Comment: @nyarlathotep - According to your link to Gustafson's Law, the speedup is still linear with respect to the number of processors added.

Comment: @mbeckish, you're right of course, but the original question related to the algorithm, so I'd tend to think of the answer in terms of algorithmic complexity, in which K is a variable.

Comment: Yep, the speedup may be superlinear, consider search space traversal with prunning (constraint satisfaction problem DFS solver (optimization problem) + prunning + shaving). With multiple cores/threads you are able from one thread prune/shave the search space of other threads...

Comment: @malejpavouk - But couldn't you do that in the non-parallel algorithm as well?  Can't you take that parallel algorithm and serialize it by turning it into multiple threads taking turns on 1 processor?

Answer (score 5):

Definite YES. Graphic cards offer parallelism, and switching from CPU to parallel computation on GPU can save a lot of time. A linear time algorithm can have a monumental speedup when executed in parallel. See [GPGPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPGPU) and "applications" section, or google for "graphic card computation".

Although you did not ask, the answer *in theory* is also definite yes, there is a complexity class NC for problems that can be "effectively parallelized" (can be solved in logarithmic time given polynomial number of processors), and "P-complete" problems which can be solved in polynomial time, but are suspected not to be in NC. (just like there are P problems and NP-complete problems, and NP-complete are suspected not to be in P)

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with your teacher as well. My argument is that many of the algorithms that are run on [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) are linear time algorithms.

For example, indexing, going over many html pages (for example all the pages in wikipedia) and looking for specific words, is an algorithm that is linear in the input. However, you can't really run it without parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

Given a large enough input, it *is* worth it. Always.

Example:
A naive algorithm to find the largest number in an unordered 'List' will just traverse the list. This will take time of the order `O(n)` to find the record.

This is okay if you have a 100, or a 1000 records.

What if you had a billion records? You split the list amongst multiple CPUs, each finds a maximum, then you have a new smaller list to work with. You can split this again => Parallel, and faster. I believe it is `O(log(n))` if you split and reduce efficiently, *and* have **n CPUs**.

The point being: If your input is big enough, `O(n)` is not good enough anymore. Depending on what needs to be done O(n) could grow to too many seconds, minutes, hours compared to what you would like.

Note: When I say `O(n)` or `O(log(n))` above, I am referring to the time taken to finish the search. i.e. *not* the 'total work' performed by all the CPUs. Usually, parallelizing an algorithm increases the total work done by the CPUs somewhat.

Comment: It can't get to better than O(n) if the problem requires checking every element.  Parallelizing can however make it faster by making checks simultaneous.

Comment: O(n) is implicitly used by most people for computation time scaling with the input size, and your answer seems to refer to the time scaling with the number of *processors* or the time scaling on a massively parallel computer (e.g. FPGA). Please qualify the `O(log n)`, it is very confusing otherwise.

Comment: @ArjunShankar - Parallelization cannot change a O(n) algorithm to O(log n), unless you have a magic machine that can allow the number of CPUs to arbitrarily increase with n.

Comment: @Don Roby: You are referring to the total work done. Yes, that can't get better. Actually, most parallelization adds slight overhead to it. I'm referring to the time taken to completion (not `time * cpu_count`)

Comment: @ArjunShankar, I think it is a mistake to say O(log(n)) where n is the number of input elements, unless you are guaranteed n CPUs.  Better to say if you have m CPUs your performance will approach O(n/m).

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin: Correct. I edited to reflect this (i.e. needing N CPUs). I won't change it the other way (i.e. m/n), because I am answering from the point of view of what is theoretically possible, rather than from the point of view of what is practical.

Comment: @ArjunShankar - It is not even theoretically possible to have the number of CPUs increase as a function of N without limit.  So even theoreticians would consider it to be O(n/m).

Comment: @mbeckish: Did I say we grow CPUs as the input size increases? Anyway, theoreticians and people in academia frequently disregard processor count when looking at theoretical bounds. Here is an example of what I believe are lecture notes for a course on Parallel Programming. http://www.cs.vassar.edu/_media/courses/cs377-200803/cs377-fall08-lect01.pdf?id=courses%3Acs377-200803%3Asep2&cache=cache It has no qualms saying 'log n' and then asking 'How many processors needed?'

Comment: @mbeckish: By the way, it is actually theoretically IMPOSSIBLE to have the algorithm I mention (search for the max number in a list) 'approach' `O(n/m)`. Even when you throw n/2 processors at n numbers, you can only do O(log(n)). Also, when you say 'm', is a constant, O(n/m) is the same is O(n).

Comment: @ArjunShankar - We may just be misunderstanding each other.  When computing the run-time complexity of parallel algorithms, the number of threads/CPUs (m) and the size of the input (n) are usually treated as independent variables.  In that case, you cannot use parallelization to change an O(n) algorithm to O(log n).  The only way to achieve this is to consider m to be a function of n.  For example, if m = n/log(n), then O(n/m) is equivalent to O(log n).

Comment: @mbeckish: Yes. You are right. The point of my answer is, if you try to find the largest of n numbers with a machine that happens to have >= n/2 processors, you can find the max in log(n) time.

Comment: @ArjunShankar - My point is that, when talking about run-time complexity, it makes no sense to say "with a machine that happens to have >= n/2 processors".  People just don't consider the number of processors to be a function of the input size when determining run-time complexity.

Comment: @mbeckish - I did not call it a function of the input size. I think you miss the point of theoretical limit. stackoverflow is now asking me if I want to move this discussion to chat, but from the way this discussion is moving, I find that rather pointless. Anyway, I could be wrong. So: Feel free to downvote my answer if you believe it is misleading, unless you have done that already. Good day!

Comment: @ArjunShankar, if you we're allowed n CPUs, and shared memory with no overhead for read, you're theoretical best of log(n) seems rather slow for this simple problem.  Say each cpu looks at the current highest value, compares it to each value in its input array, and updates the highest value if bigger, the run time approaches O(1).  I'm sticking with O(n/m), where n and m are independent variables.  I'd say for any non trivial algorithm the number of variables is far greater as is an expression for run-time complexity.

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin: So according to you, when two processors simultaneously find a number that is greater than the current greatest and then try to overwrite it simultaneously, the RAM will magically resolve the concurrent write of possibly two different numbers, and choose to store the higher one?

Comment: => Clearly, for this **simple** problem, O(n/m) is not achievable no matter how many CPUs you have, as long as your memory is CREW (concurrent read, exclusive write). But O(log n) is achievable.

Comment: @ArjunShankar, for your CREW case, the number of writes is entirely data dependent. For large datasets with either a lot of repeated data or a small possible range of values, the number of writes required will be small.  Similarly, any data that is already partially ordered will have few writes, and as the current value increases, the probability of it being exceeded reduces.  In an extreme case of all 1s and 0s, you get your O(1).  That said,  it's a moot point, as for the foreseeable future m will typically be much smaller than n, and thus the complexity approaches O(n/m).

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin: How exactly does the O(1) algorithm work? If I understand what you said earlier, the initial 'max' is a sane value, say 0. The inputs are 1, 1, 1, 1, and there are 4 processors. The processors all see they are looking at a value greater than 'max'. So they request a lock on 'max' to overwrite it. Then? They get 1 cycle each to read if the previous processor changed the value? Isn't that O(n)?

Comment: @Arjunshankar, if you check permission to write prior to attempting to write, and where that permission is not available you repeat the read and comparison stage, you stay at O(1).  e.g.  Four attempted writes of value of 1, one succeeds and writes the 1, three fail.  The three that fail then read the 1, no longer need to write, and finish.  The trick is rather than block and wait for a write, read the 'write in progress status' and act accordingly.

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin: And obviously, this falls apart when you get '1,2,3,4' and unfortunately, the processors get write permission in the order 1, 2, 3, and 4. Which is a worst case of O(n). I'm willing to bet you will now want to talk about data sets. So I guess I should just give up.

Comment: @ArjunShankar, yes for worst possible case data, with no duplication, ordered entirely unfavourably, where the processors just happen to also randomly hit the CREW result in a single combination out of n possible combinations, the run time could be O(n).  Highly unlikely however, made even more unlikely by picking a starting value randomly selected from the data.  As with algorithms like QuickSort, sometimes we favour the typical performance over the theoretical but highly improbable worst case, and optimize the implementation based on the context of our requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Given a single-core, single CPU, single machine environment, and a task which is CPU-bound, your teacher is correct.  (although it could be argued that in that case, even though you might be running multiple threads, they are not truly running in parallel, just given the illusion of running in parallel)

These days however, single core systems are rare, even many smartphones are moving to multi-core, so in practice, you will likely benefit from parallelization.  I say likely because if the tasks are small, the cost of thread creation is going to be higher than the benefits, likewise there's also context-switching that costs processor cycles.  If not done smartly, there's always the chance that making an operation parallel will in fact make it slower.