# How fast can 'finding the max in an array' possibly get?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

This question comes from a discussion that was touched off on this other question:
[Parallelize already linear-time algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604503/parallelize-already-linear-time-algorithm/8604616#8604616). It is *not* homework.

You are given an array of `N` numbers, and a machine with `P` processors and a shared `CREW` memory (Concurrent Read, Exclusive Write memory).

What is the *tightest* **upper bound** on the *fastest* algorithm to find the *largest* number in the array? [Obviously, also: What is the algorithm itself?]

I am not referring to the total amount of work performed [which can *never* be less than O(N)].

Comment: What does 'fastest' mean here? Wouldn't it depend on the relative costs of executing code, reading memory, writing memory, comparing numbers, and also on how the cache works?

Comment: @aix: You could be right. I don't mind if somebody flags it for a move there. Until then, I'm letting it stay here. It still is about programming after all.

Comment: @PaulHankin: I'm talking about complexity here. i.e. drop all the constants like '5ms' to read, '10ns' a cycle, cache hits, etc. Just consider stuff like 'read', 'write', 'compare' as 1 operation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms

Comment: @casperOne This question involve facts, and has a unique correct answer. It is not a matter of opinion, debate, polling, etc., so I think it should be re-opened.

Comment: @casperOne - Since when did people start having 'opinions' or 'polls' or 'debates' on a tight upper bound to the time taken to solve a precisely defined problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's `O(N/P') + O(Log2(P'))`, where `P'=min{N,P}`. `P'` processors search for `max` of `N/P'` elements each, followed by `Log2` pairwise merges done in parallel. The first `P'/2` merges are done by even-numbered processors, next 'P'/4' - by processors at locations divisible by 8, then by 16, and so on.

**Edit** `P'` is introduced to cover the case when you have significantly more processor nodes than the elements that you need to search.

Comment: I am not sure the Log2(P) argument holds: It assumes P % 2 == 0, also it doesn't consider the cost of distributing the work to the P processors, which I suspect to be linear

Comment: @EugenRieck Distributing can be done in O(1) by communicating `N` to all processors and assuming that they already know `P` and their own number: first processor gets `0..N/P` part of the array, second gets `N/P..2N/P', and so on. The main idea is that merging the results can be done in parallel, too: I think it is independent of the actual number of processors.

Comment: Communicating N could be as simple as writing N into a predetermined location in memory, where all CPUs can read it concurrently, so yes. I agree that communication can be done in O(1).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Consider whether this bound accounts for a rather large machine. Then every cycle, the processors can reduce the input size by half (there are so many processors that even in the first cycle, each gets only 2 numbers to compare). Ofcourse, every cycle, the number of CPUs with work to do will halve.

Comment: @ArjunShankar I think that is already accounted for: in cases where `P` is close to `N`, the value of `N/P` would be close to 1, so the result would be dominated by Log2(P).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: You are right. I see now that [1 + Log2(P)] is the same as Log2(N) when you N/2 processors :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: The obvious question is: if P >> N you mean that P*P processors will do the task slower than P processors?

Comment: @SergeDundich Your *obvious* question has as obvious an answer as the question itself. After all, this is a three-line answer in a Q&A forum, not an article in a scientific magazine. Downvoting over corner cases like this is both silly and counterproductive.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: "Downvoting over corner cases like this is both silly and counterproductive." Well. Actually it is not a corner case. The question is about **best** asymptotic time complexity. And since the user is free to grow both size of the input (N) and number of computation elements (P) the resulting computation time function is the function of those two independent parameters. Obviously time complexity function that grows with P is far from optimal (we are growing computational power to reduce computation time - not to grow it, right?) So time function provided is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: And IMO wrong answers is exactly what I'm supposed to downvote. But you have the algorithm in your answer that is very good. So I'll remove my downvote if you fix your time complexity function.

Comment: @SergeDundich The *`Log2` pairwise merges done in parallel* part should make it abundantly clear that if `P > N`, then `P-N` CPUs would have nothing to merge. I could have added a note saying that `P` is the *effective* number of processors needed for the computation, but anyone with even a passing familiarity with the subject takes it for granted that CPUs not used in a computation do not contribute to the cost of a computation. So the answer is not wrong, let alone being *fundamentally* wrong.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: So fix or remove your time complexity function and I'll remove my downvote. Is that a problem? IMO time complexity function is important part of the answer (see e.g. sdcvvc's answer that gives the correct function) and IMO having this part wrong is a good reason for downvote. (to be continued)

Comment: (continue) @dasblinkenlight: I believe the function is wrong because two natural parameters for this function are size of the input (N) and number of computation elements (P) that are **independent of each other and not related to any specific algorithm**. If you use other parameters (e.g. number of computational elements actually used by _your_ algorithm that **depends on both N and P and specific to your algorithm**) then you have to specify them explicitly. Otherwise the function is incomplete and probably misleading (since you defined P as just number of CPUs it is just wrong).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: You can just write the correct function class `O(N/P) + O( Log2( max{P,N} )`.

Comment: @SergeDundich Isn't it `min{P,N}`, rather than `max{P,N}`? I think a better way to deal with it is to redefine `P` as `P'=min{P,N}`, and use it instead: `O(N/P') + O(Log2(P'))`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: "I think a better way to deal with it is to redefine `P` as `P'=min{P,N}`, and use it instead: `O(N/P') + O(Log2(P'))`" IMO doesn't matter. I personally prefer defining additional parameters (like `P'`) only if it makes function significantly more readable (which is IMO not this case) but it is equally correct.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: "Isn't it min{P,N}, rather than max{P,N}?" True. Of course it is. Just a typo. Of course I mean `O(N/P) + O(Log2(min{P,N}))`.

Comment: you don't need additional parameter P', complexity can be written as `O(N/P + log N)` (why - left for the reader)

Answer (score 5):

Cook, Dwork, and Reischuk showed that any CREW algorithm for finding the maximum of n elements must run in Omega(lg n) time, even with an unlimited number of processors and unlimited memory. If I remember correctly, an algorithm with a matching upper bound appears in their paper:

Stephen Cook, Cynthia Dwork, and Rüdiger Reischuk. Upper and lower time bounds for parallel random access machines without simultaneous writes. SIAM Journal on Computing, 15(1):87-97, 1986.

Answer (score 4):

The following is optimal bound:

If p <= n/log n you can do it in O(n/p) time; otherwise it's O(log n) i.e. when p>n/log n you gain nothing compared to p=n/log n.

Proof - lower bound:

Claim 1: You can never do faster than Ω(n/p), because p processors can give only speedup of p

Claim 2: You can never do faster than Ω(log n), because of CREW model (see unforgiven's paper); if you want to check if a 0-1 array has at least one 1, you need O(log n) time.

Proof - upper bound:

Claim 3: You can find maximum using n/log n processors and in O(log n) time

Proof: It is easy to find maximum using n processors and log n time; but in fact, in this algorithm most processors are dormant most of the time; by suitable dovetailing, (see e.g. Papadimitriou's complexity book) their number can be lowered to n/log n.

---

Now, given less than n/log n processors you can give work assigned to K processors to 1 processor, this divides processor requirement by K and multiplies required time by K.

Let K=(n/log n)/p; the previous algorithm runs in time O(K log n) = O(n/p), and requires n / (log n * K) = p processors.

---

Edited: I just realized that when p <= n/log n, dasblinkenlight's algorithm has the same asymptotic runtime:

n/p + log p <= n/p + log(n/log n) <= n/p + log n <= n/p + n/p <= 2n/p = O(n/p)

so you can use that algorithm, which has complexity O(n/p) when p <= n/log n and O(log n) otherwise.

Comment: +1 for a well thought of answer, and for considering the issues raised by two other answers.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this to be O(N/P)+O(P)

- Sharing the work between P processors has a cost of O(P)
- combining the work done by P processors has also costs of O(P)
- A perfect parallell search of N items by P processors has time cost of O(N/P)

My naive algorithm would be to

- write item 0 into a CREW cell labelled "result"
- start P completly independent searches, each through 1/P th of the N items
- upon completion of each search use CAS spinloop to replace "result" with result of partial search, if it is larger. (Depending on your definition of CREW you might not need the spinloop)

Comment: This analysis is way too pessimistic even on real hardware that we actually have. Reducing a value from `P` processors can be done in `O(lg P)` time.

Comment: The obvious question is: if P >> N you mean that 2P processors will do the task slower than P processors?

Answer (score 1):

For P=N^2 it is O(1).

All initialize Boolean array CannotBeMax[i] = FALSE

Proc (i,j) sets CannotBeMax[i] = A[i] < A[j]

Max is A[CannotBeMax[i] == FALSE]

Note that all concurrent writes attempt to write identical info so the answer is consistent no matter which one succeeds.

Comment: Right. +1. The algorithm you describe, while correct, is relevant for a [CRCW PRAM with the 'common' write scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Random_Access_Machine). My question was specifically for a CREW (Concurrent Read, Exclusive Write) machine, where concurrent writes are not allowed.